# switch xampp version from 1.6.8 to xampp 1.8.3 error

Tags: php, web, xampp

I made a website using XAMPP version 1.6.8 and then I install the new version of XAMPP 1.8.3
Now my Login code worked on 1.6.8 but doesnt work on 1.8.3.

the error is

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\karimunjawa\admin\ceklogin.php on line 61
```

the line 61 is

```
</html>
```

ceklogin.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login</title>

<?php
                    //session_start();
                    include "../include/koneksi.inc";

                    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
                        $username = $_POST['username'];
                        $password = $_POST['password'];
                        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$username' && password='$password'");
                        $num = mysql_num_rows($sql);
                        if($num==1) {
                        // login benar //
                        //session_register("admin");
                        //$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                        //$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                        ?><script language="JavaScript">alert('Anda berhasil login... Selamat datang <?php echo $_SESSION['username']           ?>..!!'                          );
                    document.location='adminfiles/'</script><?
                    } else {
                    // jika login salah
                    ?><script language="JavaScript">alert('Username atau password Anda
                    salah'); document.location='index.php'</script><?
                    }
                    }
                    ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style2 {color: #000000}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
        <form action="" name="login" method="post">
        <table width="279" height="110" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0px">
          <tr>
            <td height="26" align="center" bgcolor="#993300"> <h3> Login Administrator </h3> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="32" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><span class="style2">Username atau Password salah!!</span></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td height="37" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="index.php"> Ulangi Login </a> </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#993300">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
  </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me
thanks

Comment: Please show us the full code

Comment: That error is usually a missing `}`  somewhere.

Comment: Its probably got more to do with the fact the code was written and **?tested?** on 1.6.8 where you had turned off all error reporting and when you installed the new release you have not turned it off. Maybe you should leave error reporting ON and fix all the bad code you wrote!